# dplyr: filter based on another column

Tags: r

Let's say that I have the following data and am interested in grabbing data by date where the type is "ts". Of course, there are dates where ts is not available, and I need to revert to the 'real' values for those dates.

```
dat = data.frame(dte = c("2011-01-01","2011-02-01","2011-03-01","2011-04-01","2011-05-01",
                         "2011-01-01","2011-02-01","2011-03-01"),
                 type = c("real","real","real","real","real","ts","ts","ts"),
                 value=rnorm(8))
dat

cpy = dat %>% dplyr::filter(type == "ts") 

cpy
```

How can something like that be done in dplyr.

Expected output is:

```
dte            type    value
"2011-01-01"   ts      ....
"2011-02-01"   ts
"2011-03-01"   ts  
"2011-04-01"   real
"2011-05-01"   real
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you have NA values for dte where type is "ts".  In that case, please show a reproducible example

Comment: But your expected output also shows `real` for `type`

Comment: Added. And no NA values, just missing date values where it's not present.

Comment: yes, if ts is available, use that. otherwise, use the real value.

Comment: I posted a solution.  Please check if that is what you wanted.  What about the 'value' column.  Does it remain NA for the 'real'?

Comment: yes, it remains na for the 'real'

Comment: In that case, my solution gives the output you wanted.

Comment: actually, the 'real' values are needed in the final output

Comment: I think there was a confusion.  I updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

One idea could be to `group_by()` date and keep values where `type == "ts"` or when, for a given date, there are no `type == "ts"`, keep the other value:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(dte) %>%
  filter(type == "ts" | !any(type == "ts"))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
#Groups: dte [5]
#
#         dte   type      value
#      <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl>
#1 2011-04-01   real  0.2522234
#2 2011-05-01   real -0.8919211
#3 2011-01-01     ts  0.4356833
#4 2011-02-01     ts -1.2375384
#5 2011-03-01     ts -0.2242679
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with base packages,

```
rbind(dat[dat$type == "ts",], dat[!unique(dat$dte) %in% 
                                               dat[dat$type == "ts","dte"], ])

#     dte     type       value
#6 2011-01-01   ts -0.98109206
#7 2011-02-01   ts  1.67626166
#8 2011-03-01   ts -0.06997343
#4 2011-04-01 real  1.27243996
#5 2011-05-01 real -1.63594680
```

Taking the rows with `type` equal to `ts` and `rbind`ing the remaining dates from the `real` type.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can also use `which.max`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(dte) %>%
    slice(which.max(factor(type)))    
#        dte   type      value
#      <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl>
#1 2011-01-01     ts -0.5052456
#2 2011-02-01     ts -0.4038810
#3 2011-03-01     ts -1.5349627
#4 2011-04-01   real  1.6812035
#5 2011-05-01   real -0.9902754
```

---

Or using a similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .SD[which.max(factor(type))] , dte]
#        dte type      value
#1: 2011-01-01   ts -0.5052456
#2: 2011-02-01   ts -0.4038810
#3: 2011-03-01   ts -1.5349627
#4: 2011-04-01 real  1.6812035
#5: 2011-05-01 real -0.9902754
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep values `"ts"` for a given date when possible and if not, keep `"real"`. At least that is what I inferred from question and comments.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Thanks,for the comment.  I updated the post with data.table.