# Filter column based on other character column (in R)

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I would like to use `dplyr` so that when two rows have the same Label but different Type, only the one with type "big" is kept.

**Current structure**

`df <- data.frame(Label = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), Type = c("big", "small", "big", "small", "tall", "short"))`

**Desired df**

`df_clean <- data.frame(Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Type = c("big", "big", "tall", "short"))`

The premise is that `big > small` and `tall > small`

PD: my real dataframe has other categories but there are also hierarchies.

Thank you!

Comment: sure there are lots of duplicates.  Perhaps this one for example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396516/dplyr-filter-based-on-another-column

Comment: @InesGuardans I've updatet my answer to account for the new requirement. Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Label = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), 
                  Type = c("big", "small", "big", "small", "tall", "short"))
```

This solution works also for the new constraint, as long as the preference order is

big > tall > small > short

(which is the same as your requirement, except for that if big and tall appear together, big will be chosen (and small respectively))

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Type = factor(Type, levels = c( "big", "tall", "small", "short"))) %>% 
  group_by(Label) %>% 
  arrange(Type) %>% 
  summarise(Type = first(Type))
```

Returns:

```
  Label Type 
  <chr> <fct>
1 A     big  
2 B     big  
3 C     tall 
4 D     short
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Label) %>% filter(if(n() > 1) Type == 'big' else TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Label [3]
  Label Type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     big  
2 B     big  
3 C     small
```

Comment: It doesn't entirely work because there are several hierarchies in my real dataset.

`df <- data.frame(Label = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), Type = c("big", "small", "big", "small", "tall", "short"))`

If we add categories "tall", "short", I want A to be "big" (big>small) and C to be "tall" (tall>small)